# regex help in extracting values from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in javascript like

```
"some text @[14cd3:+Seldum Kype] things are going good for @[7f8ef3:+Kerry Williams] so its ok"
```

From this i want to extract the name and id for the 2 people. so data like -

```
[ { id: 14cd3, name : Seldum Kype},
  { id: 7f8ef3, name : Kerry Williams} ]
```

how can u use regex to extract this?

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var text = "some text @[14cd3:+Seldum Kype] things are going " +
           "good for @[7f8ef3:+Kerry Williams] so its ok"

var data = text.match(/@\[.+?\]/g).map(function(m) {
    var match = m.substring(2, m.length - 1).split(':+');
    return {id: match[0], name: match[1]};
})
// => [ { id: '14cd3', name: 'Seldum Kype' },
//    { id: '7f8ef3', name: 'Kerry Williams' } ]

// For demo
document.getElementById('output').innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the id from Group index 1 and name from group index 2.

```
@\[([a-z\d]+):\+([^\[\]]+)\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cI0sX1/4)

**Explanation:**

- `@` Matches a literal `@` symbol.
- `\[` Matches a literal `[` symbol.
- `([a-z\d]+)` Captures one or more chars lowercase alphabets or digits.
- `:\+` Matches `:+` literally.
- `([^\[\]]+)` Captures any character but not of `[` or `]` one or more times.
- `\]` A literal `]` symbol.

Comment: What does the last `+` do?

Comment: repeats the previous token one or more times.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, the key is to properly escape reserved special symbols:

```
@\[([\d\w]+):\+([\s\w]+)\]
```